# Watchdog is disabled, still it seems to restart my system

Tags: debian, watchdog

My machine is restarting a short time after I run a certain binary. I believe the reason is the watchdog, because when I remove `/dev/watchdog` and `/dev/watchdog0`, I can run the binary without problems. However, I prefer a proper solution to an workaround. (Autorunning a script at every boot that deletes aforesaid files would seem like workaround for me as well.)

Here's the current watchdog state:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~$ sudo sysctl kernel | grep watchdog
kernel.nmi_watchdog = 0
kernel.soft_watchdog = 1
kernel.watchdog = 1
kernel.watchdog_cpumask = 0-3
kernel.watchdog_thresh = 10
```

Then I disable the `soft_watchdog`:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~$ sudo sysctl kernel.soft_watchdog=0
kernel.soft_watchdog = 0
```

New watchdog state: (Note, that `kernel.watchdog` state changed as well.)

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~$ sudo sysctl kernel | grep watchdog
kernel.nmi_watchdog = 0
kernel.soft_watchdog = 0
kernel.watchdog = 0
kernel.watchdog_cpumask = 0-3
kernel.watchdog_thresh = 10
```

Then, when running my binary, still the machine is restarting.

I'm running `Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)`

Addendum: `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` does not print anything between starting my binary and system restart.

Addendum 2: The binary I'm talking about is produced by our build system. If I remember correctly, this problem came only after running our build in Docker. However, something broke my local build system, so I can't check that.

Comment: Is the binary run as a user/group which currently has access to the watchdog node?  Does it need to be?

Comment: @sourcejedi: The watchdog nodes belong to user `root` and group `root`.  The binary is run inside docker which is run with `docker run --privileged`. The man page then says, that "When the operator executes docker run --privileged, Docker will enable access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in AppArmor to allow the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside of a container on the host." Unfortunately we need the `--privileged` switch for USB communication.